# Web traffic analytics

Tags: php, analytics, web-traffic

The site that I am working on creates user sites like (domain.com/user). We want to show the users some web traffic statistics relevant to their own site, like how many views from facebook, twitter etc. Can you guys please recommend a solution which we can integrate into our PHP/MySQL based system? Or is it better to build one inside the system ourselves using mangoDB or something similar?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For preference, unless you are using SSL, I would recommend implementing the sites as user.example.com/ rather than domain.com/user - it's much easier to configure your webserver to write seeprate log files / most off the shelf web analytics packages will split a log file from multiple vhosts into reports per vhost.

There's lots of tools available off the shelf - piwik, awstats, webalizer, analog

Google analytics is amazingly good value compared to most commercial offerings.

If you need to persist with your current naming schema, then consider using a too which relies on page tagging rather than log analysis.

> Or is it better to build one inside the system ourselves using mangoDB or something similar?

I'd suggest that's very much a last resort - if you can't find what you need, then I'd recommend forking one of the open source packages.

Comment: is there a way i can track web traffic/traffic origin with PHP?

Comment: IS there a way to track web traffic with PHP? Yes lots. Is there a way *you* can track web traffic with PHP? That depends on your skills. Post a new, specific question.

Comment: already have. [feel free to add to the discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57208956/7543162)