# Track Web Traffic with PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics, web-traffic

**Is there an effective way to track web traffic (or at least the origin of web traffic) with PHP?**

I was thinking of using custom canonical links for each search engine and other websites, which would mean anybody who visits `mywebsite.com` without a parameter is likely direct traffic. But then I would somehow need to change the `href` value of the `link rel='canonical'` element for each engine crawler (e.g. `https://mywebsite.com/?ref=google`, `https://mywebsite.com/?ref=duckduckgo`, etc), and I'm not exactly sure how to go about this (through robots.txt, `meta` tags or?).

I really don't want to use Google Analytics if I don't have to. I'd prefer to have all of my analytics under one roof so to speak, but I'm stuck for ideas of how to achieve this, and most of my searches on SO seem to pull up stuff related GA.

Comment: an explanation for the downvote would be nice

Comment: What web traffic are you trying to track?  You can use the `Referer` header in most cases.  If you want to track links that you hand out, some sort of query string parameter like you've proposed is a good idea.

Comment: @Brad yeah i know i can use url parameters to track certain links, but im more so wondering how track search engine traffic specifically? ive read that the `referer` header is unreliable af

Comment: If you're going to base all of your assumptions on some article you read, please link to it so we can clarify it.  The `Referer` header is all you have.  Web analytics are fuzzy anyway, so if you need some sort of exact numbers, I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: @Brad well ive read all over SO about how in many cases the header can be and is omitted in many contexts such as bookmarks, AV software, browser extensions, switching from `http` to `https`, etc. roughly how often is the `referer` header omitted? im not looking for exact numbers, but i would of course like to have numbers that are as accurate as possible. id like to get an idea of what traffic is direct and what traffic is not direct and where non-direct traffic is coming from. does GA rely on the `referer` header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> well ive read all over SO about how in many cases the header can be and is simply omitted for various reasons such as AV software, browser extensions, switching from http to https, etc? is this often the case?

Yes, this can happen.  How often *for your particular site's visitors* is anyone's guess.

> does GA rely on the referer header?

Not quite... as Google Analytics runs client-side, it's getting that information from `document.referrer`, which contains the same value as what is sent in the `Referer` header.

> but i would of course like to have numbers that are as accurate as possible

With any web analytics, there are things you simply can't measure.  The best way is to use a client-side analytics script to send data to your server.  There are a handful of reasons why this is better than simply looking at the data you get in the HTTP request data in PHP:

- Pages can be cached, so you'll be able to see page loads at times when the browser never even checked in with your server to load the page.
- The [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) is available, allowing you to track specific load timings that you can work to improve on over time.
- In most browsers, you can use the [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) to get a sense for when the user leaves the page, so you have accurate time-on-page measurements.

> id like to get an idea of what traffic is direct and what traffic is not direct and where non-direct traffic is coming from

`document.referrer` is what you want, and gets you as close to accurate as you can get.

Comment: If the value for `document.referrer` is derived from `HTTP_REFERER`, does that mean `document.referrer` is just as or no more accurate than `HTTP_REFERER` in the grand scheme of things? Would creating my own approach to tracking this on the client or server side be just as accurate/reliable as GA?

Comment: Correct, you won't get any better or worse accuracy with `document.referrer` than with the `Referer` request header.  Tracking this client-side is equivalent to what Google Analytics does at the core.  I also suspect Google Analytics has some secret sauce internally for dealing with spam since they can aggregate data across all sites that use them, but this is unlikely to be a problem for you.  In fact, if you do your own custom analytics, you might actually see more legit traffic than Google Analytics since you probably won't be blocked by the usual filters, at least not initially.

Comment: i guess you answered my questions in your edit. really appreciate your help buddy!! <3

Comment: hey one last question: what is the benefit of using `document.referrer` over the `$_SEVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?